# $\int_{E} f d\mu = 0 $ and $f(x)>0$ imply $\mu (E) = 0$ is true?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ (X, \mathfrak M, \mu ) $ be a measure space, $\mu$ positive measure and 
$ f : X \longrightarrow \mathbb R \cup \{+ \infty\} $ a measurable function.

it's true that $\int_{E} f d\mu = 0 $ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in X $ imply $\mu (E) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, since it implies $f\cdot 1_E = 0$ $\mu$-a.e.

Comment: Why is this equality true? I'm thinking in this way $1_E(x)=1 $ for all $x \in E$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E_{n}=\{x \in E: f(x) \geq n^{-1}\}$.
Since $f> 0$, obtain $\int_{E_n}f d\mu \geq 0$.
Also , $f>0$ and $E_n \subset E$ implies that
$\int_{E_n}f d\mu \leq \int_{E}f d\mu = 0$.
Putting the inequalities together, conclude that
$\int_{E_n}f d\mu =0$.
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
 0=\int_{E_n}f d\mu 
 &\geq \int_{E_n}n^{-1}d\mu
 = n^{-1}\mu(E_n) \\
\end{align*}
Conclude that $\mu(E_n)=0$. 
Since $E = \cup_{n}E_n$,
obtain $\mu(E)=0$.

Comment: thank you so much. Your answer has solved my doubts. several times I can not solve simple problems. thank you!